# typeScript error 'module, class, interface, enum, import or statement' expected

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to understand why this line invokes an error:

```
const value = 20 * 30;
```

error TS1008: Unexpected token; 'module, class, interface, enum, import or statement' expected.

any idea?

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4869

Comment: Which ECMAScript version are you using ? 5 or 6 ?

Comment: Please add more details - i.e. TypeScript version and a longer snippet which provides the error.

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio ? If yes, did you update to the latest version of TypeScript (see https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b1fff87e-d68b-4266-8bba-46fad76bbf22)

Comment: When running tsc version I get : Version 1.0.3.0 and when running where tsc I get: 1.0 and 1.7 versions. I added 1.7 in PATH variables

Comment: Thanks. I fixed it. There was a problem in the JSON file

Answer (score 11):

Here is the solution:

Earlier on my machine I had installed Visual Studio 2015 Pro Edition. that had installed TypeScript 1.0.3.0. and added its path to system environment.

Now I used `npm install -g TypeScript` and it did install, however from command line, typing `tsc --version` was always giving 1.0.3.0.

I removed the older path from environment and then restarted code and it worked fine.

Better you check your versions and the solution might help.

Comment: Please let me know how you removed the older path from the environment? I ran into the exact same issue.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't cause an error for me: https://jsfiddle.net/n0w1jt7b/

```
const value = 20 * 30; // 600
```

Be sure that all your versions are up-to-date.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed it. There was a problem in the JSON file